# Minecraft Towny - Only build in plots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-towny

In my Minecraft Bukkit server, we have Towny installed. If players belong to the town, they can build anywhere inside it. Is there a way to limit the players to only be able to build in plots that they own in the town?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. I haven't read the Towny docs for a while now, but you can set up mayor/assistant/resident permissions using the in game commands.

This will allow you to choose exactly who builds where, set mob spawns/fire spread/explosions/pvp... it goes on.

The best way to learn it is play with it yourself.

Try something like `/mayor help` and just keep diving in to the list of commands.

Good luck! :D

Answer (score 2):

You first have to be the mayor of a town, then it's a few simple commands.

```
/town set perm off
```

The command above stops everybody from building, destroying, using items or using switches anywhere except their own plot (except the mayor and I am not sure but I think the assistant).

You can also enable/disable individual permissions (build, destroy, item or switch) on a group of people (resident, outsider, ally or friend):

```
/town set perm outsider destroy off
```

You can also switch all permissions on or off on a group of people:

```
/town set perm resident on
```

Last but not least is that you can switch permissions on only one plot not all of the town. This can be used to allow your friend to do stuff on your plot or hire an outsider for a job.  Few examples below:

```
/plot set perm on (everyone is alowed to do anything he wants on this plot)
/plot set perm friend on (all your friends are allowed to doanything they want on this plot)
/plot set perm friend build on (friends are allowed only to build on this plot)
```

There is also the ability to switch the town or a plot to have fire, mobs, pvp or explosions. These work via toggle rather than having to state `on` or `off`.

```
/town toggle fire 
/plot toggle pvp
```